# Offset of record field as constant

Tags: delphi, constants, offset, record

I'm using a technique like the following to get offsets of record fields at runtime:

```
procedure DoSomethingWithVar(var AField);
DoSomethingWithVar(TGUID(nil^).D3); // TGUID and D3 for exposition only :-)
```

This works fine. Now I want to have these offsets as `const`s but can't get it to work:

```
const
  cMyVarTyped: Pointer = @TGUID(nil^).D3;
  cMyVarUntyped = @TGUID(nil^).D3;
  cMyOffsetTyped: INT_PTR = INT_PTR(@TGUID(nil^).D3);
  cMyOffsetUntyped = INT_PTR(@TGUID(nil^).D3);
```

All of them yield "E2026 Constant expression expected". Any ideas?

FWIW: Wrapping the declaration in `{$WRITEABLECONST ON}`/`{$WRITEABLECONST OFF}` doesn't change the error.

Comment: Maybe you can do something with [Writeable typed constants](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Writeable_typed_constants_(Delphi)) at runtime

Comment: @RemyLebeau The offset constants would be part of a const `array[TSomeEnum] of TSomeRecord`. I already considered making it into a `var` but would prefer to retain the constness.

Comment: That [idea with writable constant](https://pastebin.com/XDUdUzCi) is not so bad (of course in cost of writable constant).

Comment: As I need an `array of record` I already have a typed const, so all I'd loose by using writeable const or a `var` is the compile time const correctness. It will be a semi-ugly compromise in any way, so I'm staying with my current solution which is a function GetOffset consisting of a `case TSomeEnum of`.

Comment: "*Wrapping the declaration in {$WRITEABLECONST ON} doesn't change the error*" - I wasn't suggesting that it would magically make the declarations work at compile-time. By making the constants writable, you can then assign them dynamically at run-time, such as in an `initialization` block. Did you try that? `const {$J+} cMyVarTyped: Pointer = nil; ... initialization cMyVarTyped := @TGUID(nil^).D3;`

Comment: @Remy what on earth is the point of using writeable typed constants for this. Or indeed for anything. If you want a global variable, well, use a global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to get the compiler to make a constant expression containing a member offset.